# How to use a NOT in a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the query below and would like to remove the subquery as it is slowing the query down. I have tried a LEFT JOIN, but it is returning zero results. How can I remove the subquery?

```
SELECT DISTINCT releases.* 
FROM releases
INNER JOIN artist_love ON  releases.all_artists LIKE CONCAT('%',artist_love.artist,'%')
                           AND artist_love.user =  'Quickinho'
INNER JOIN label_love ON label_love.label = releases.label_no_country
                         AND label_love.user =  'Quickinho'
                         AND releases.id NOT IN 
                                        (
                                            SELECT release_id
                                            FROM charts_extended
                                            WHERE artist =  'Quickinho'
                                        )    
ORDER BY releases.date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 102
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT releases.* 
FROM releases
INNER JOIN artist_love ON  releases.all_artists LIKE CONCAT('%',artist_love.artist,'%')
AND artist_love.user =  'Quickinho'
INNER JOIN label_love ON label_love.label = releases.label_no_country
AND label_love.user =  'Quickinho'
left join charts_extended on charts_extended.release_id=label_love=releases.id and charts_extended.artist =  'Quickinho'
where charts_extended.release_id is null
ORDER BY releases.date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 102
```